# Indoor Positioning and iBeacons

Tags: ios, swift, gps, ibeacon

So I had this idea for an app that requires  the position of a user's iPhone inside of a indoor area, like a house. I was going to use GPS and CoreLocation, but I realized that GPS services are bad/don't work indoors (for the accuracy I need, which is about +/- 3 meters). I heard of iBeacons and did some research on them to see if I could place those around "the house" and get the devices position in relation to the iBeacon. But, I read that they don't have good positioning since after ~10 meters the positioning isn't accurate. I am still sort of new to app development and was wondering if there was a way to accomplish device positioning indoors? Are their iBeacons with accurate range for positioning?

If this is the wrong place to post this, please redirect me to the right place :)

Comment: for your inspiration we did this project with iBeacon as indoor navigation system for visual impaired, https://vimeo.com/155723148 and https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/guidebelt-maytham-fahmi?trk=prof-post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You explained that your project requires the position of a user's iPhone inside of a indoor area. I have helped deploy beacons for museums and cabaret bars in Japan. The cabarets send out advertisements to clients in the vicinity and further detailed advertisements when clients enter the premises. The set up for a good indoor location system using beacons is pretty straight forward and interesting. Beacons are a great solution for detecting when people move into some vaguely defined area, or when reaction time is of little importance. But there are other alternatives as discussed below.

Though it depends on the intended use and immediate surroundings as well, generally one can detect the presence of beacons as far away as 50-70 meters or as little as 10 inches.

It should also be noted that the basic signal strength can be set at different levels so the meaning of immediate, near, far (and out of range) can be very different for the same iBeacon at different settings.

For example at low power you could detect a threshold 30cm at +/- 5cm accuracy after 10 seconds, and the signal could not be detected at 10m. At full power you could probably detect a 10m treshold +/- 50cm after about 10 seconds. This signal could be detected at 50-70 but with huge fluctuations.

David's answer is actually referring to **Mass Effect** which increases the overall accuracy / triangulation of BLE.

### **New methods and technologies**

**The Real-time Locating System (RTLS) market**

**AoA**

Accuracy of iBeacons is based on RSSI (Received Signal Strength Indication). RSSI is very sensitive to interference i.e. environment and even body interference. However, these factors don't affect the direction of the radio signal, so with the **Angle-of-Arrival method** it is possible to achieve continuous accuracy even down to a few centimeters, in real-time with BLE devices.

AoA Uses advanced antennas and locators to measure the direction (Angle-of-Arrival) of a radio signal transmitted by a tag. The result is sent to a positioning engine, which uses advanced algorithms to compute the tag's position and creates outputs in various formats. Many companies already use these systems.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am unaware of any way to determine the Angle of Arrival using a mobile phone, as the antennas on the BLE chips and antennas on mobile phones simply don't support this.  While this may work for other use cases, it doesn't sound like a solution here.

Comment: @davidgyoung I saw some mobile phone support bluetooth version 5.1 and 5.2 now, so is it work now?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  Having a Bluetooth 5.1 or 5.2 capable chip is only one of many requirements for AoA distance distance estimation.  You also need an antenna array designed specifically for this purpose (typically larger than a mobile phone) and firmware and operating system support.  To my knowledge, no phone manufacturers have built a full system to support this, nor has any even put together the necessary components.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience there isn't really anything native that's reliable within short distances like that.

The accuracy of GPS can vary pretty significantly depending on the specific connection and GPS fences can be error prone.

iBeacons seem promising, but due to the realities of bluetooth it can be strongly affected by anything coming in between the two devices including bodies, which is a problem when a device is often in people's pocket.

The other problem with iBeacons is something in the API seems either faulty, or unreliable. I'm unsure if this is a software or hardware issue, but regardless there are issues with the device keeping track of which beacons are and are not connected, with the notifications of entering/leaving a range being unreliable for consistent usage.

TLDR, IMO if you're looking for something more reliable than GPS, you're probably currently out luck :(

Comment: Yea, I guess so. iBeacons seem promising, but with the limitations I guess I can't use it. Thank you very much for the answer :)

Comment: If apple improves the performance it could be really useful, that's what I'm hoping for :-\

Comment: One additional issue is that the user must have bluetooth on and your app must be active or in a background state. If your app isn't open or being used fairly often, it's unlikely your app will even have a chance to work with the detection.

Answer (score 1):

the **CoreLocation Beacons detection APIs in iOS don't really give you something equivalent to GPS**.  GPS APIs will tell you "The phone is at these coordinates."  Beacon APIs will tell you "The phone is near this beacon."

The simplest way to tell you where you are within a house using beacons is to put a bunch of beacons around the house in different rooms, and perhaps at multiple locations within rooms.  But because beacon signals can travel 40 meters or more, you'll often see multiple beacons at the same time.  So you end up with APIs that tell you "The phone is near this list of beacons." You can then take the list of beacons that you are near, find which is closest based on the rough distance estimates the APIs provide, and you can assume that you are at the position specified by the closest beacon.

Doing all of this requires you to assign unique identifiers to each beacon, and have some kind of lookup table or database (either embedded in your app or exposed as a web service) that maps each beacon identifier to a meaningful location.  For example:

```
Beacon ID     Floor    Coordinates (meters from house NW corner)
65000         1        16, 23
65001         1        9, 45
65002         2        11, 14
```

Building all this is not trivial.  Beacons provide a basic building block to setting it up, but it isn't quit as easy as getting a pair of coordinates from GPS.

Comment: This is greatly appreciated, thank you very much for the explanation. How practical is using beacons in this manner for a very large area, say a 1 story mall? As stated by @PEEJWEEJ bluetooth is strongly affected by people getting in the way of the signals, which is very much the case in a mall.

Comment: This technique requires lots of beacons, yes.  A the Consumer Electronics Show 2016, a large number of exhibit halls were covered with over 1000 beacons.